# How to export rendered forge viewer as glTF file?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I gonna export the rendered forge viewer as glTF file using three.js so I can save that.
The code is like below.

```
const exportGLTF = () => {
  var scene = viewer.impl.sceneAfter;
  exporter.parse( scene, function ( gltf ) {
    const output = JSON.stringify( gltf, null, 2 );
    saveString( output, 'scene.gltf' );
  }, {trs: true} );
}
```

But it output the empty gltf file.(Like the result below.)

```
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "2.0",
    "generator": "THREE.GLTFExporter"
  },
  "scenes": [
    {
      "nodes": [],
      "name": "AuxScene"
    }
  ],
  "scene": 0
}
```

I think getting scene from forge viewer is not working.(`var scene = viewer.impl.sceneAfter;`)
So if anybody has experience in this part, help me, please.

Comment: From our VS Code Extension 'Autodesk Forge' you can generate the gltf. Also here is the code the extension uses to create that - https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools/blob/2a406c4fc7d0135eeef2e451dbfedc12534cd321/src/commands/model-derivative.ts#L652

Comment: I want to generate that on a web server, not on my local.

Comment: do you need Forge services (Model Derivative) to translate the model to glTF? Currently, Forge service has not supported this translation. However, the code Jaime shared can be merged to your server and run on your server side. Will this be an alterative to you?